# What is the Preprocessor define to disable the Warning "GetVersionExW': was declared deprecated"

Tags: c, winapi, visual-studio-2015, warnings, windows-7-x64

I'm not allowed to change the code. So I can not use `#pragma`. So my Question is what is the Preprocessor define that I need to pass to the compiler to disable the warning of the function `GetVersionExW`?

I tried:

- `_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS`
- `_CRT_NONSTDC_NO_DEPRECATE`
- `_WINSOCK_DEPRECATED_NO_WARNINGS`
- `_CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE`

Comment: Don't use that function/macro, it's not available from Windows 8.1

Comment: _I'm not allowed to change the code_: why do you have this requirement ?

Comment: I tought there is a way to solve it without pragma as I could solve the rest without pragmas and #ifdef

Comment: "*Don't use that function/macro, it's not available from Windows 8.1*" - that is completely untrue.  The function itself is available, it is simply that it exhibits new behavior on 8.1 and later depending on how your app is manifested. The real question is, why is the code using `GetVersionEx()` to begin with? What is the code trying to solve by retrieving the (potentially simulated) OS version number that can't be solved in a different and more reliable way?

Answer (score 4):

The API call `GetVersionExW` is declared using [__declspec(deprecated)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/044swk7y.aspx). There is no way to disable a warning for particular API call.

Your only option is to disable [Warning C4996](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ttcz0bys.aspx) altogether, either through a preprocessor [pragma warning](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2c8f766e.aspx) before including the respective header file, or globally in the project settings (compiler option [/wd](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/thxezb7y.aspx)).

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
#pragma warning(disable: <warning number>)
```

Comment: He wrote: _I'm not allowed to change the code. So I can not use #pragma._ Not (yet) downvoted.

Comment: Actually I won't downvote because the answer is still correct, even if it doesn't meet the OP's (somewhat strange) requirements.

Comment: Sorry for being strang. I just know that answer allready and tried to avoid it. +1

Comment: That pragma has a command line equivalent, `/Wd`. Just know that unless you have a proper manifest, Windows 10 will lie to you with that function and say Windows 8.1.